# English Translation of Gastronomie Pratique

Tags: cookbook, french-cuisine

I was reading Julia Child's autobiography, and she mentioned that she loved the book Gastronomie Pratique by Ali-Bab. It's apparently a classic compendium of French cooking recipes and techniques. Does anybody have a particular translation they recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is apparently an english version however there are whole sections missing and it is poorly translated. You are far better off going with a different book or if you have the time taking up french. The Book I went with was Larousse Gastronomique which has been endorsed by Heston Blumenthal and Gordon Ramsay.

[http://www.amazon.com/New-Larousse-Gastronomique-Hamlyn/dp/0600620425/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1302582324&sr=1-3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0600620425)

Comment: Thanks. I've been eyeing this one, and I think I'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to have been an english translation of this book. Info [here](http://openlibrary.org/books/OL6655253M/Gastronomie_pratique) on all editions.

Comment: I know that there are a few. For instance, McGraw Hill published a translation by Elizabeth Beston a while back.

Comment: Do you have a link for it? I haven't had any luck looking for it...

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Encyclopedia-Practical-Gastronomy-Ali-Bab/dp/0070010625/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1301249285&sr=8-1